# Samsung Tablet 7.0 plus and 7.7 unable to debug devices

Tags: java, android, adb, samsung-mobile

I have a problem of debugging samsung tablet device on my ubuntu.
in My case I am using:

1. ubuntu 11.04
2. android-sdk tools version 17.0
3. android-sdk Platform-tools version 11.0
4. Samsung tablet 7.0 plus and 7.7 , android-os version is 3.2

when I connect my device to my ubuntu computer the command "adb devices" as show
"???????????     device", then i cannot debug or install my application on the device.
it was working for Samsung Tablet 8.9 and 10.1. I try to do something as below:

1. restart adb server (adb kill-server && adb start-server)
2. restart adb server as root (sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server)
3. check udev and permission to be "a+rx" then restart udev and restart adb
4. stop adb (adb kill-server) start adb with usb mode (adb usb)
5. Add vendor id to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

All of these solution is not work and I have notice that when the device is turn off and connected to my computer while is charge, the command "adb devices" is list as normal like "2E83E...  device" and also the same as when I turn it on while device is in bootloader, after the device ready the command "adb devices" is show above which I cannot do anything with that device.

I wonder if there are any trick or something that I have to do with android-sdk or with my ubuntu to solve this problem.

Thanks you very much for adviser.

Thanks Veasna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to debug an application running on GT-P6200 (that should be 7.0 Plus) and had the same kind of problem: it just won't show up in adb.

Every now and then it *would*, without me doing anything special. There are a lot of people complaining about that on the Internet and nobody has a working solution or a workaround.

I suspect it is some kind of a bug in Samsung firmware, and there is not much we can do about it until Samsung decides developers are important and fixes that problem.

(Perhaps that will happen if and when they release the ICS upgrade for that tablet.)

Comment: ok, I agree with you it may a bug in Samsung. But my friend they was using ubuntu the same as me and it work without any problem and also for mac os it's work very well. I just don't know why it's not working in my case, may it some kind of bug as you say. thanks andri

Comment: Interesting. If it works for him, please ask for the *exact* model number and firmware version -- it's possible that some specific version isn't affected by this particular bug. It would be interesting to know if I ever have to deal with that particular tablet model again.

Comment: actually, I was working with a company to develop mobile phone application. My friend and I was in the same theme and we was using the same device. I have been ask him how he configure it and he said, he configure it follow the Android site. I have not idea what is the problem seem there are 6 people in the same theme and his computer is the only one which working fine with those devices. I also copy all the android-sdk from him to my computer but it still the same result. anyway thanks for your answer.